# Recursion and Tail Call Optimization Example

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I am trying to study Elixir and function programming and have had trouble understanding this example in the book Elixir in Action.

```
defmodule ListHelper do
  def sum([]), do: 0
  def sum([head | tail]) do
    head + sum(tail)
  end
end

ListHelper.sum([12,3,4])
```

The return value of this is 19, but what I am not understanding is how the values are being accumulated.

I thought head was being continuously updated and then when the pattern matched to `[]` then the accumulated head would be added to `0` and the function would exit, but after playing with it I'm now thinking that's not what's going on. Can someone offer an alternative explanation for what's going on in this example? If I need to explain some more I can try to revisit this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sum([head | tail])` is `head + sum(tail)`, so `sum([12,3,4])` is `12 + sum([3,4])`, `sum([3,4])` is `3 + sum([4])` and `sum([4])` is `4 + sum([])`. `sum([])` is `0`, so in total we get:

```
sum([12,3,4]) = 12 + sum([3,4])
              = 12 + 3 + sum([4])
              = 12 + 3 + 4 + sum([])
              = 12 + 3 + 4 + 0
              = 19
```

---

The recursive call to `sum` isn't a tail-call, so no tail-call optimization will happen here. To make it TCO, one needs to make a recursive call to `sum` to be the last one.

```
defmodule ListHelper do
  def sum([], acc), do: acc
  def sum([head | tail], acc),
    do: sum(tail, acc + head)
end

ListHelper.sum([12,3,4], 0)
#⇒ 19
```

Comment: Still confused how head is being tracked on each next call. How does each next call know what the previous values of head were?

Comment: @adamscott It doesn't. `sum([3,4])` is 7. In order to calculate that, it doesn't need to know that the "previous" value of `head` was 12. The 12 doesn't matter for the value of `sum([3,4])`.

Comment: Okay I think I'm getting it so this is saying 12 pause for execution with the tail of the array, 3 pause, 4 pause, and then because we hit the pattern for a blank array that does not call the recursion then the calls start finishing and we add 0 + 4 + 3 + 12 for the total?

Comment: @adamscott, basically that is correct.  Since the recursive call isn't in tail position it can't be tail call optimized so it is handled like any other recursive call would be.

Answer (score 3):

> I thought head was being continuously updated...

Nope. A new, separate `head` variable is created for each call to `sum()`.  That is accomplished by creating a new *stack frame*, where a frame contains all the local variables created by the function call--including the parameter variables like `head`.

If you write something like:

```
x = 3 + func1()
```

elixir has to evaluate `func1()` in order to calculate a value for the `x` variable.  And, the definition of `func1()` may create its own `x` variable, so elixir allocates a new stack frame to calculate the return value of `func1()`.  Once elixir calculates the return value of `func1()`, that value is substituted into the line above:

```
           42
            |
            V

x = 3 + func1()

x = 3 + 42
x = 45
```

...and elixir can calculate a value for the `x` variable.

The same thing happens if you write:

```
4 + sum([5,6,7])
```

The only difference is that elixir will allocate many stack frames on the stack to calculate the return value of `sum([5,6,7])`.  With a recursive function call, the return value of each stack frame will depend on the return value of another stack frame.  Only when the base case is reached, and `sum([])` returns `0` can elixir start filling in the required values inside each stack frame to calculate a return value.

```
  4 + sum([5,6,7]) 
           |  
           |
     #1    V  sum([5,6,7])
   +--------------------+              
   | head = 5           |              
   | tail = [6,7]       |              
   |                    |             
   | return:            |            
   |   head + sum(tail) |                    
   |    5 +  sum([6,7]) |
   +-------------|------+
                 |
        #2       V  sum([6,7])
      +----------------------+   
      | head = 6             |    
      | tail = [7]           |   
      |                      |        
      | return:              |             
      |     head + sum(tail) |         
      |       6  + sum([7])  |
      +-----------------|----+
                        |        
            #3          V  sum([7])
          +----------------------+     
          | head = 7             |     
          | tail = []            |     
          |                      |     
          | return:              |     
          |     head + sum(tail) |     
          |       7  + sum([])   |     
          +----------------|-----+      
                           |
                #4         V   sum([])
             +-----------------------+
             |  return: 0            |
             +-----------------------+
```

Note that there are three separate `head` variables in existence at the same time.  Once the bottom stack frame returns, that sets in motion the following steps:

```
 4 + sum([5,6,7]) 
           ^
           | 
           +---18-----------<----------+
   +--------------------+              |
   | head = 5           |              |
   | tail = [6,7]       |              |
   |                    |              ^
   | return:            |              |
   |   head + sum(tail) |              |      
   |    5 +  sum([6,7]) ---->---18-----+  #7
   +-------------^------+
                 |
                 +--13------<----------+
      +----------------------+         |
      | head = 6             |         |
      | tail = [7]           |         |
      |                      |         ^
      | return:              |         |     
      |     head + sum(tail) |         |
      |       6  + sum([7]) -|-->--13--+  #6
      +-----------------^----+
                        |        
                        +---7--<-------+
          +----------------------+     |
          | head = 7             |     ^
          | tail = []            |     |
          |                      |     |
          | return:              |     ^
          |     head + sum(tail) |     |
          |       7  + sum([]) --|>--7-+     
          +----------------^-----+      
                           |
                           +----0--<---+
               +-----------------+     |
               |  return: 0    --|>--0-+  #5
               +-----------------+
```

If you add some print statements to your code, you can see how the steps are performed:

```
defmodule My do
  def sum([]) do
    IO.puts("Inside sum([]):\n\treturning 0")
    0
  end
  def sum([head | tail]) do
    IO.puts("Inside sum([head|tail]), head=#{head} tail=#{inspect(tail, charlists: :as_lists)}")
    val = head + sum(tail)
    IO.puts("Inside sum([head|tail]), head=#{head} tail=#{inspect(tail, charlists: :as_lists)}")
    IO.puts("\treturning #{val}")
    val
  end
end

My.sum([5,6,7])
```

At the command line:

```
~/elixir_programs$ elixir a.exs
Inside sum([head|tail]), head=5 tail=[6, 7]
Inside sum([head|tail]), head=6 tail=[7]
Inside sum([head|tail]), head=7 tail=[]
Inside sum([]):
    returning 0
Inside sum([head|tail]), head=7 tail=[]
    returning 7
Inside sum([head|tail]), head=6 tail=[7]
    returning 13
Inside sum([head|tail]), head=5 tail=[6, 7]
    returning 18
```